# Confirmation of thread safety with std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++11, thread-safety, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

My application has an IRC module that essentially is a normal client. Since this is heavily threaded, I stand the risk of a plug-in retrieving, for example, a users nickname - it is valid at the time, but the parser triggers an update, changing said nickname. 
Once the other thread has execution again, it's dealing with a pointer to now-invalid memory, since it'll be impossible to have the return + copy as an atomic operation.

Is my assumption about this correct, based on the code below? As such, I guess I'd have to use the usual mutex lock/unlock method, unless someone can confirm or suggest otherwise (I'd rather not have to convert and return a shared_ptr, but I guess it is a valid option, it's just I intend on SWIG'ing this and don't know if it wouldn't like them).

IrcUser.h

```
class IrcUser : public IrcSubject
{
private:
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<std::string>    _nickname;
    std::shared_ptr<std::string>    _ident;
    std::shared_ptr<std::string>    _hostmask;
public:
    ...
    const c8*
    Ident() const
    { return _ident.get()->c_str(); }

    const c8*
    Hostmask() const
    { return _hostmask.get()->c_str(); }

    const u16
    Modes() const
    { return _modes; }

    const c8*
    Nickname() const
    { return _nickname.get()->c_str(); }

    bool
    Update(
        const c8 *new_nickname,
        const c8 *new_ident,
        const c8 *new_hostmask,
        const mode_update *new_modes
    );
};
```

IrcUser.cc

```
bool
IrcUser::Update(
    const c8 *new_nickname,
    const c8 *new_ident,
    const c8 *new_hostmask,
    const mode_update *new_modes
)
{
    if ( new_nickname != nullptr )
    {
        if ( _nickname == nullptr )
        {
            *_nickname = std::string(new_nickname);
        }
        else
        {
            _nickname.reset();
            *_nickname = std::string(new_nickname);
        }

        Notify(SN_NicknameChange, new_nickname);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code has a race condition, and therefore undefined behaviour, as there is a potential read (the `->get()`) and write (the `.reset()` or `=`) on the same object (a `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` instance) from separate threads: access to the `std::shared_ptr`s must be synchronized.

Note locking a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) within the getter and returning the `c_str()` is insufficient as the caller of the getter would be using the result of `c_str()` outside of the lock: the getter needs to return a `shared_ptr` by value.

To correct:

- add a `std::mutex` to `IrcUser` (note this now makes the class non-copyable):

  ```
  mutable std::mutex mtx_; // Must be mutable for use within 'const'
  ```
- lock the `std::mutex` in the getters and `Update()`, using a [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) for exception safety:

  ```
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> Nickname() const
  {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mtx_);
      return _nickname;
  }

  bool IrcUser::Update(const c8 *new_nickname,
                       const c8 *new_ident,
                       const c8 *new_hostmask,
                       const mode_update *new_modes)
  {
      if (new_nickname)
      {
          {
              std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mtx_);
              _nickname.reset(new std::string(new_nickname));
          }
          // No reason to hold the lock here.
          Notify(SN_NicknameChange, new_nickname);
      }

      return true;
  }
  ```

Consider just using a `std::string` if the copying is acceptable as the `shared_ptr` may be adding unnecessary complexity.

Comment: C++11 defines `std::atomic_...` free functions to be specialized for `std::shared_ptr` (see my answer). I think it's a shame the OP accepted the answer so soon here. +1

Comment: Another great answer - I'll change my choice once I've done some testing as these definitely provide greater detail and alternatives, as some client code needs looking over. :)

Comment: @sehe, was unware of that cheers (+1). Currently working my wa through atomics and memory model.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest that locking on such finegrained levels is likely (way) overkill.

I'd suggest doing atomic updates to the IrcUser object itself, which could be *lock-free* depending on your library implementation and target architecture. Here is a sample that uses

- `std::atomic_is_lock_free<std::shared_ptr>`
- `std::atomic_load<std::shared_ptr>`
- `std::atomic_store<std::shared_ptr>`

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic for documentation.

**Disclaimer** *I don't know how many compilers/C++ library implementations already implement this C++11 feature.*

Here's what it'd would look like:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct IrcSubject {};
typedef char c8;
typedef uint16_t u16;
typedef u16 mode_update;

class IrcUser : public IrcSubject
{
    private:
        // ...
        std::string _nickname;
        std::string _ident;
        std::string _hostmask;
        u16         _modes;
    public:
        IrcUser(std::string nickname, std::string ident, std::string hostmask, u16 modes)
            : _nickname(nickname), _ident(ident), _hostmask(hostmask), _modes(modes) { }
        // ...
        std::string const& Ident()    const { return _ident; }
        std::string const& Hostmask() const { return _hostmask; }
        const u16          Modes()    const { return _modes; }
        std::string const& Nickname() const { return _nickname; }
};

//IrcUser.cc
bool Update(std::shared_ptr<IrcUser>& user,
    std::string new_nickname,
    std::string new_ident,
    std::string new_hostmask,
    const mode_update *new_modes
)
{
    auto new_usr = std::make_shared<IrcUser>(std::move(new_nickname), std::move(new_ident), std::move(new_hostmask), *new_modes /* ??? */);
    std::atomic_store(&user, new_usr);
    //Notify(SN_NicknameChange, new_nickname);
    return true;
}

bool Foo(IrcUser const& user)
{
    // no need for locking, user is thread safe
}

int main()
{
    auto user = std::make_shared<IrcUser>("nick", "ident", "hostmask", 0x1e);

    mode_update no_clue = 0x04;
    Update(user, "Nick", "Ident", "Hostmask", &no_clue);

    {
        auto keepref = std::atomic_load(&user);
        Foo(*keepref);
    }
}
```

Comment: Had to +1 for the mode_update guesswork + bits alone :P `struct mode_update
{
 bool erase_existing;
 u16 to_add;
 u16 to_remove;
};` Great concept there - as IrcUser is a shared_ptr within the IrcChannel, this might well work nicely - and as you said, so many lock/unlocks for this is indeed overkill. Will give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a race condition can occur with nickname that results in your getters accessing bad memory. shared_ptrs are only thread safe with regards to their ownership symantics. You will need to add some form of synchronization for their values.