# Can shared_ptr.get() be called by multiple threads while another thread locks and calls shared_ptr.swap()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, concurrency

I would like to know if this is safe with shared_ptr.  Pardon my pseudo code:

```
Thread 1:
do lock
ReadOnlyObj obj = make_shared<ReadOnlyObj>();
some_shared_ptr.swap(obj);
do unlock

Thread 2-N:
//no lock
some_shared_ptr->getterOnObj();
```

CPP reference says

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and **any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur**, the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

but, according to the [GNU docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/memory.html#std.util.memory.shared_ptr):

> **The Boost shared_ptr (as used in GCC) features a clever lock-free algorithm to avoid the race condition**, but this relies on the processor supporting an atomic Compare-And-Swap instruction. For other platforms there are fall-backs using mutex locks. Boost (as of version 1.35) includes several different implementations and the preprocessor selects one based on the compiler, standard library, platform etc. For the version of shared_ptr in libstdc++ the compiler and library are fixed, which makes things much simpler: we have an atomic CAS or we don't, see Lock Policy below for details.

as far as I know, intel x86_64 supports CAS.

So, to my question:

shared_ptr::swap is non-const.   get and ->() are const.   Do I have to lock on get/->, too, given my usage scenario listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself in the [boost docs.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety)

```
//--- Example 3 ---

// thread A
p = p3; // reads p3, writes p

// thread B
p3.reset(); // writes p3; undefined, simultaneous read/write
```

What I'm trying to do is a simultaneous read and write, which is undefined/not safe.

Comment: That's correct. `shared_ptr`'s internal synchronization is for cases where you have two different `shared_ptr`s that point to the same shared object with a shared internal reference count. It doesn't apply to concurrent access to the same `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Note that c++11 defines [atomics for `shared_ptr<>` too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16490228/85371) (which may or not be [`std::atomic_is_lock_free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic). So there's a possible solution without using heavy weight (such as mutexes).