# An attempt to create atomic reference counting is failing with deadlock. Is this the right approach?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

So I'm attempting to create copy-on-write map that uses an attempt at atomic reference counting on the read-side to not have locking.

Something isn't quite right.  I see some references getting over-incremented and some are going down negative, so something isn't really atomic.  In my tests I have 10 reader threads looping 100 times each doing a get() and 1 writer thread doing 100 writes.

It gets stuck in the writer because some of the references never go down to zero, even though they should.

I'm attempting to use the 128-bit DCAS technique laid [explained by this blog](http://blog.memsql.com/common-pitfalls-in-writing-lock-free-algorithms/).

Is there something blatantly wrong with this or is there an easier way to debugging this rather than playing with it in the debugger?

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> StringMap;

static const int zero = 0;  //provides an l-value for asm code

class NonBlockingReadMapCAS {

public:

    class OctaWordMapWrapper {
    public:
        StringMap* fStringMap;
        //std::atomic<int> fCounter;
        int64_t fCounter;

        OctaWordMapWrapper(OctaWordMapWrapper* copy) : fStringMap(new StringMap(*copy->fStringMap)), fCounter(0) { }

        OctaWordMapWrapper() : fStringMap(new StringMap), fCounter(0) { }

        ~OctaWordMapWrapper() {
            delete fStringMap;
        }

        /**
         * Does a compare and swap on an octa-word - in this case, our two adjacent class members fStringMap 
         * pointer and fCounter.
         */
        static bool inline doubleCAS(OctaWordMapWrapper* target, StringMap* compareMap, int64_t compareCounter, StringMap* swapMap, int64_t swapCounter ) {
            bool cas_result;
            __asm__ __volatile__
            (
             "lock cmpxchg16b %0;"    // cmpxchg16b sets ZF on success
             "setz       %3;"         // if ZF set, set cas_result to 1

             : "+m" (*target),
               "+a" (compareMap),     //compare target's stringmap pointer to compareMap
               "+d" (compareCounter), //compare target's counter to compareCounter
               "=q" (cas_result)      //results
             : "b"  (swapMap),        //swap target's stringmap pointer with swapMap
               "c"  (swapCounter)     //swap target's counter with swapCounter
             : "cc", "memory"
             );
            return cas_result;
        }



    OctaWordMapWrapper* atomicIncrementAndGetPointer()
    {

        if (doubleCAS(this, this->fStringMap, this->fCounter, this->fStringMap, this->fCounter +1))
            return this;
        else
            return NULL;
    }


        OctaWordMapWrapper* atomicDecrement()
        {
            while(true) {
                if (doubleCAS(this, this->fStringMap, this->fCounter, this->fStringMap, this->fCounter -1))
                    break;
            }
            return this;
        }

        bool atomicSwapWhenNotReferenced(StringMap* newMap)
        {
            return doubleCAS(this, this->fStringMap, zero, newMap, 0);
        }
    }
    __attribute__((aligned(16)));

    std::atomic<OctaWordMapWrapper*> fReadMapReference;
    pthread_mutex_t fMutex;


    NonBlockingReadMapCAS()  {
        fReadMapReference = new OctaWordMapWrapper();
    }

    ~NonBlockingReadMapCAS() {
       delete fReadMapReference;
    }

    bool contains(const char* key) {
        std::string keyStr(key);
        return contains(keyStr);
    }

    bool contains(std::string &key) {
        OctaWordMapWrapper *map;
        do {
            map = fReadMapReference.load()->atomicIncrementAndGetPointer();
        } while (!map);
        bool result = map->fStringMap->count(key) != 0;
        map->atomicDecrement();
        return result;
    }

    std::string get(const char* key) {
        std::string keyStr(key);
        return get(keyStr);
    }

    std::string get(std::string &key) {
        OctaWordMapWrapper *map;
        do {
            map = fReadMapReference.load()->atomicIncrementAndGetPointer();
        } while (!map);
        //std::cout << "inc " << map->fStringMap << " cnt " << map->fCounter << "\n";
        std::string value = map->fStringMap->at(key);
        map->atomicDecrement();
        return value;
    }

    void put(const char* key, const char* value) {
        std::string keyStr(key);
        std::string valueStr(value);
        put(keyStr, valueStr);
    }

    void put(std::string &key, std::string &value) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&fMutex);
        OctaWordMapWrapper *oldWrapper = fReadMapReference;
        OctaWordMapWrapper *newWrapper = new OctaWordMapWrapper(oldWrapper);
        std::pair<std::string, std::string> kvPair(key, value);
        newWrapper->fStringMap->insert(kvPair);
        fReadMapReference.store(newWrapper);
        std::cout << oldWrapper->fCounter << "\n";
        while (oldWrapper->fCounter > 0);
        delete oldWrapper;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fMutex);

    }

    void clear() {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&fMutex);
        OctaWordMapWrapper *oldWrapper = fReadMapReference;
        OctaWordMapWrapper *newWrapper = new OctaWordMapWrapper(oldWrapper);
        fReadMapReference.store(newWrapper);
        while (oldWrapper->fCounter > 0);
        delete oldWrapper;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&fMutex);

    }

};
```

Comment: From just a quick look: What happens in atomicIncrementAndGetPointer if doubleCAS fails?  While it will call again, what value would get sent for compareCounter?  You are passing this->fCounter, but since this element is not volatile, won't the old value get passed?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd  Thanks for taking a look.  I rearranged the code so that fReadMapReference gets reloaded and resent if the CAS fails.  Still hanging, but I think what you pointed out was a problem anyway.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `__sync_val_compare_and_swap()`?

Comment: What looks like a sure recipe for disaster is that you don't properly control copying and assignment, i.e. the "Law of Three". That and the IMHO overuse of dynamic allocation make it hard to get this code right. Clean up that code first, with luck, you will get compiler errors at some point where you didn't expect it and where it caused erroneous behaviour.

Comment: There seem to be quite a few pieces of useless code, such as `void *p2 = map->fStringMap`, or function `atomicDecrement` returning a value. Try to do a bit of cleanup, leaving only what's relevant. It might help users who are trying to help you out with it...

Comment: why are you trying to implement your own reference counting? Why do you try to implement your own atomic operations?

Comment: @jalf Because atomic reference counting and lock-free concurrent datastructures do not exist on my pre-c++11 platform.  Locking is too slow in my use-case.

Comment: @marathon `boost::shared_ptr` implements atomic reference-counting.

Comment: @jalf It's not thread-safe.  See example 3.  Also the boost::atomic functions for shared_ptr are not lockfree on my platform (x64/linux) (atomic_is_lock_free returns() false! which is really disappointing)  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety

Comment: @marathon Incidentally, you misunderstand the meaning of "thread-safety" in this context. Boost's `shared_ptr` is exactly as thread-safe as any other C++ type, and in particular, its reference counting is perfectly thread-safe. What's not thread-safe in example 3 is that two different threads are attempting to modify the same `shared_ptr<T>` **object** at the same time — not merely use shared_ptrs to take references to the same `T` object (which is perfectly safe), but access a `shared_ptr<T>` simultaneously from two different threads with no synchronization.

Comment: @Quuxplusone pretty sure what I want to do is unsafe with shared_ptr, and the atomic shared_ptr stuff uses locks.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682444/can-shared-ptr-get-be-called-by-multiple-threads-while-another-thread-locks-an

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe not the answer but this looks suspicious to me:

```
while (oldWrapper->fCounter > 0);
delete oldWrapper;
```

You could have a reader thread just entering `atomicIncrementAndGetPointer()` when the counter is 0 thus pulling the rug underneath the reader thread by deleting the wrapper.

Edit to sum up the comments below for potential solution:

The best implementation I'm aware of is to move `fCounter` from `OctaWordMapWrapper` to `fReadMapReference` (You don't need the `OctaWordMapWrapper` class at all actually). When the counter is zero swap the pointer in your writer. Because you can have high contention of reader threads which essentially blocks the writer indefinitely you can have highest bit of `fCounter` allocated for reader lock, i.e. while this bit is set the readers spin until the bit is cleared. The writer sets this bit (`__sync_fetch_and_or()`) when it's about to change the pointer, waits for the counter to fall down to zero (i.e. existing readers finish their work) and then swap the pointer and clears the bit.

This approach should be waterproof, though it's obviously blocking readers upon writes. I don't know if this is acceptable in your situation and ideally you would like this to be non-blocking.

The code would look something like this (not tested!):

```
class NonBlockingReadMapCAS
{
public:
  NonBlockingReadMapCAS() :m_ptr(0), m_counter(0) {}

private:
  StringMap *acquire_read()
  {
    while(1)
    {
      uint32_t counter=atom_inc(m_counter);
      if(!(counter&0x80000000))
        return m_ptr;
      atom_dec(m_counter);
      while(m_counter&0x80000000);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  void release_read()
  {
    atom_dec(m_counter);
  }

  void acquire_write()
  {
    uint32_t counter=atom_or(m_counter, 0x80000000);
    assert(!(counter&0x80000000));
    while(m_counter&0x7fffffff);
  }

  void release_write()
  {
    atom_and(m_counter, uint32_t(0x7fffffff));
  }

  StringMap *volatile m_ptr;
  volatile uint32_t m_counter;
};
```

Just call acquire/release_read/write() before & after accessing the pointer for read/write. Replace `atom_inc/dec/or/and()` with `__sync_fetch_and_add()`, `__sync_fetch_and_sub()`, `__sync_fetch_and_or()` and `__sync_fetch_and_and()` respectively. You don't need `doubleCAS()` for this actually.

As noted correctly by @Quuxplusone in a comment below this is single producer & multiple consumer implementation. I modified the code to assert properly to enforce this.

Comment: While I agree about the "busy waiting" while loop -- the notify/wait pattern would probably be preferable there, I think that there isn't any risk of readers accessing `oldWrapper` when the `fCounter` gets to `0` b/c earlier in the `put()` method the `fReadMapReference` member was swapped for a new one such that all subsequent reader threads after that point will use `newWrapper` and not `oldWrapper`.  The effect of the while loop is to wait for any *existing* reader threads (there prior to the swap) to finish before `oldWrapper` is deleted, thus avoiding pulling the rug out from any of them.

Comment: @Turix I know that's the intention but it doesn't work. Once the reader thread has loaded `fReadMapReference` there's a window that writer thread could invalidate the pointer by deleting it. Think about breaking `fReadMapReference.load()->atomicIncrementAndGetPointer()` to two lines and putting Sleep(1000) just after `fReadMapReference.load()` but before `atomicIncrementAndGetPointer()`.

Comment: @Turix I think proper way to do this would be to add counter to `fReadMapReference` instead and try to swap it in the writer thread when the counter is 0. Once it's swapped you can safely delete the pointer.

Comment: Good call (+1). I agree and would recommend you win the bounty.

Comment: so, only do the swap if fReadMapReference.fCounter is 0?  With a high number of reader threads constantly, this may never happen.  My idea was to move it away so new readers wouldn't touch it and delete it after the current readers have gone away.  But I guess as you point out, there is a window for failure here.

Comment: @marathon Maybe there's a better way but you could reserve highest bit of `fReadMapReference.fCounter` for "reader lock", i.e. if this bit is set readers spin. The bit is set by writer when it's about to change the pointer and waits for the counter to drop down to 0 before it swaps the pointer. That would prevent writers locking infinitely at least.

Comment: Btw, you don't have to use the `doubleCAS()` in your `atomicDecrement()` but can just use `__sync_sub_and_fetch()` (since the pointer can't change when fCounter>0) and you should use `__sync_val_compare_and_swap()` instead of inline asm in your `doubleCAS()`

Comment: Notice that (as of 2014-07-24 at least) NonBlockingReadMapCAS above assumes that there is only one writer thread. If any thread attempts to call `NonBlockingReadMapCAS::acquire_write` while any other thread already holds the writer lock, everything breaks. (You could add an `assert` to verify this precondition at the top of `acquire_write`.)

Comment: writes should be infrequent in my use-case, so blocking reads during writes is fine.   I should be able to use boost::atomic<uin32_t> for the atom_inc/dec/or/and() stuff, too.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are probably lots of problems, but here are the obvious two.

The most trivial bug is in `atomicIncrementAndGetPointer`. You wrote:

```
if (doubleCAS(this, this->fStringMap, this->fCounter, this->fStringMap, this->fCounter +1))
```

That is, you're attempting to increment `this->fCounter` in a lock-free way. But it doesn't work, because you're fetching the old value twice with no guarantee that the same value is read each time. Consider the following sequence of events:

- Thread A fetches `this->fCounter` (with value 0) and computes argument 5 as `this->fCounter +1` = `1`.
- Thread B successfully increments the counter.
- Thread A fetches `this->fCounter` (with value 1) and computes argument 3 as `this->fCounter` = `1`.
- Thread A executes `doubleCAS(this, this->fStringMap, 1, this->fStringMap, 1)`. It succeeds, of course, but we've lost the "increment" we were trying to do.

What you wanted is more like

```
StringMap* oldMap = this->fStringMap;
int64_t oldCounter = this->fCounter;
if (doubleCAS(this, oldMap, oldValue, oldMap, oldValue+1))
    ...
```

The other obvious problem is that there's a **data race** between `get` and `put`. Consider the following sequence of events:

- Thread A begins to execute `get`: it fetches `fReadMapReference.load()` and prepares to execute `atomicIncrementAndGetPointer` on that memory address.
- Thread B finishes executing `put`: it deletes that memory address. (It is within its rights to do so, because the wrapper's reference count is still at zero.)
- Thread A starts executing `atomicIncrementAndGetPointer` on the deleted memory address. If you're lucky, you segfault, but of course in practice you probably won't.

As explained in the blog post:

> The garbage collection interface is omitted, but in real applications you would need to scan the hazard pointers before deleting a node.

Answer (score 2):

Another user has suggested a similar approach, but if you are compiling with gcc (and perhaps with clang), you could use the intrinsic __sync_add_and_fetch_4 which does something similar to what your assembly code does, and is likely much more portable.
I have used it when I implemented refcounting in an Ada library (but the algorithm remains the same).

```
int __sync_add_and_fetch_4 (int* ptr, int value);
// increments the value pointed to by ptr by value, and returns the new value
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure how your reader threads work, I suspect your problem is that you are not catching  and handling possible `out_of_range` exceptions in your `get()` method that might arise from this line:  `std::string value = map->fStringMap->at(key);`.  Note that if `key` is not found in the map, this will throw, and exit the function without decrementing the counter, which would lead to the condition you describe (of getting stuck in the while-loop within the writer thread while waiting for the counters to decrement).

In any event, whether this is the cause of the issues you're seeing or not, you definitely need to either handle this exception (and any others) or modify your code such that there's no risk of a throw.  For the `at()` method, I would probably just use `find()` instead, and then check the iterator it returns.  However, more generally, I would suggest using the **RAII** pattern to ensure that you don't let any unexpected exceptions escape without unlocking/decrementing.  For example, you might check out `boost::scoped_lock` to wrap your `fMutex` and then write something simple like this for the OctaWordMapWrapper increment/decrement:

```
class ScopedAtomicMapReader
{
public:
    explicit ScopedAtomicMapReader(std::atomic<OctaWordMapWrapper*>& map) : fMap(NULL) { 
        do {
            fMap = map.load()->atomicIncrementAndGetPointer();
        } while (NULL == fMap);
    }

    ~ScopedAtomicMapReader() {
        if (NULL != fMap)
            fMap->atomicDecrement();
    }

    OctaWordMapWrapper* map(void) {
        return fMap;
    }

private:
    OctaWordMapWrapper* fMap;

}; // class ScopedAtomicMapReader
```

With something like that, then for example, your `contains()` and `get()` methods would simplify to (and be immune to exceptions):

```
bool contains(std::string &key) {
    ScopedAtomicMapReader mapWrapper(fReadMapReference);
    return (mapWrapper.map()->fStringMap->count(key) != 0);
}

std::string get(std::string &key) {
    ScopedAtomicMapReader mapWrapper(fReadMapReference);
    return mapWrapper.map()->fStringMap->at(key);    // Now it's fine if this throws...
}
```

Finally, although I don't think you should *have* to do this, you might also try declaring `fCounter` as `volatile` as well (given your access to it in the while-loop in the `put()` method will be on a different thread than the writes to it on the reader threads.

Hope this helps!

By the way, one other minor thing:  `fReadMapReference` is leaking.  I think you should delete this in your destructor.

Comment: Thanks.  Those are all good points.  I wasn't allowing at()'s to be called in my tests with keys that weren't there.  But as you say I should handle the exception cases and fix the dtor.