# boost lock variable vector during update

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

several (2 or more) client threads need to run at a high frequency, but once every 1 minute a background service thread updates a variable used by the main threads.

whats is the best method of locking a variable -- in fact, a vector -- during the small moment of update with little impact on the client threads.

there is no need to protect the vector during 'normal' (no background thread) operation since all threads utilize the values.

boost::thread is used with a endless while loop to update the vector and sleep for 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This seems like a good occasion for a Reader-Writer lock. All the clients lock the vector for reading only, and the background service thread locks it for writing only once every minute.

   - [`SharedLockable` concept from c++14](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.shared_lockable)
   - which is implemented in Boost Thread as `boost::shared_mutex`

     > The class `boost::shared_mutex` provides an implementation of a multiple-reader / single-writer mutex. It implements the `SharedLockable` concept.
     >
     > Multiple concurrent calls to `lock()`, `try_lock()`, `try_lock_for()`, `try_lock_until()`, `timed_lock()`, `lock_shared()`, `try_lock_shared_for()`, `try_lock_shared_until()`, `try_lock_shared()` and `timed_lock_shared()` are permitted.
2. That said, depending on your actual platform and CPU model you could get more lucky with an atomic variable.

   If it's a primitive value, just using `boost::atomic_int` or similar would be fine. For a vector, consider using std::shared_ptr (which has atomic support).See e.g.

   - [Confirmation of thread safety with std::unique_ptr/std::shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16489772/confirmation-of-thread-safety-with-stdunique-ptr-stdshared-ptr/16490228#16490228)

   You can also do without the dynamic allocation (although, you're using vector already) by using two vectors, and switching a reference to the "actual" version atomically.

Comment: sharedlockable sounds ideal based on the description "This is the standard multiple-reader / single-write model" thnx

Comment: the switching/swapping the reference also seems to make sense. thereby avoiding any read locking.

Comment: hmm. if the vector size changes thats a problem.

Comment: @GabeRainbow How so? It's only a problem if you hold stale references or otherwise bypass the public interface of the vector class. By now to be giving more specific useful advice, we'd need to know more about what exactly you're trying to achieve (on a functional level).

Comment: workable but requires a longer lock period -- for readers. hopefully small impact. thanks

Comment: In my experience it's not hard to prevent reallocation (using `.reserve`). Otherwise, using a deque with a pool allocator would be nice.